# Invoke a server side action upon the user pressing the Enter/Return key

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

**Updated**

Since I got your very helpful answers to this question so promptly, I have reconsidered the problem. I think I need to break it down into two small requirements, so I am updating the question.

In my ASP.NET MVC 4 application, I need that when the user presses the enter key on the keyboard while the focus is in a specific textbox:

*Scenario 1: The appropriate server side action must be called. If the user presses the enter key when the cursor is in a different text box, another action must be called.*

*Scenario 2: If the user pressed the Enter key on the keyboard while the focus is in **any** textbox in one of the forms on the current page, the form must be posted back with all the form data (HttpPost) to the action on the controller as specified in the action attribute of that `<form>`.*

How do I accomplish these two scenarios?

Comment: Do you want to pass any values to the action being called ?

Comment: Yes, essentially, I want to post-back to a specific action on a specific controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#idOfTextbox').keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
        $.ajax({
        //.. Your values go here...
        });
    }
});
```

If you want to intercept a submitted form, you can use the [ajaxForm plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/). This way, you can have several forms on the page and when a form is submitted, it will make an AJAX call to the action method specified in the form's action attribute. You will then be able to handle the response in the 'success' callback of the ajax call.

Comment: Thank you. How do I invoke a server side MVC action on a controller from here?

Comment: $.ajax({
  url: '/PathToYourActionMethod',
  success: function(data) {
  }
});

Comment: Thank you. And if I want it the same action to be called for all textboxes, I assume I'll be replacing that #idOfTextBox with a certain CSS classname or something?

Comment: Yes. In the example, I am referencing the textbox by an id. To attach it to several textboxes, you should use a common class name.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I've somewhat re-considered the problem and broken it down into two scenarios. You've answered the first scenario already. If you could please help me with the second one, that'll help me a lot.

Comment: I assume I must simply do a form.submit(); in the keydown event if the keycode is 13.

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript or simply put each input in a different `<form>` with a button type="submit" inside.

Comment: That's interesting. Thank you. I never thought about that. :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
element.onkeydown = function(event) {
    //do something on keydown (enter is keyCode === 13)
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as below:

```
$('#idOfTextbox').keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
       $.ajax({

       url: './savedata',//Your method name, that is to be called
       type: 'POST',
       contentType: 'application/json',//Type of data you want to post
       data: JSON.stringify({ obj: sampleobject }),//object of post-object i.e. data being posted
       success: function(result) {
       //Logic to handle success
        }  
       error: function(){}//Handle error here  
     }
});
```

I have given an example to call a method that is on the same controller on whose view you are currently working with..

Comment: Thank you very much indeed, Bhushan.

Comment: Is JSON.stringify a jQuery method or a server side MVC method?

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2:..it is jquery method...moreover any method in MVC that is used in jquery has @ prepended to it...!!

Comment: That's what I suspected. How will jQuery recognize the data I want to post. The data I want to post will have a server-side representation from my model/view model. I won't have a client side object. You're saying I'll have to make an object on the client side first and then call stringify to serialize it?

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2: obj in stringify method should be the parameter to the method you are posting data to...otherwise it doesn,t work...

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2: yes you will have to create an object ...!!

Comment: Thanks much. I'd give the correct answer to you, but Queti answered it first. Sorry about that. :-)

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2:..No worries, but I was using another method and while I was typing my answer, he posted that. I thought it was better than my method so took it from there...Glad to help you...

Comment: Glad to receive your expert help. I am sure there'll be a next time soon. :-)